# vue 3 before create event in main.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-options-api

I'm trying to use `beforeCreate` in `main.js`. What is the equivalence of this code in Vue 3?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  components: { App },
  store: store,
  beforeCreate() { this.$store.commit('initialiseStore');},
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`beforeCreate()`](https://vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle.html#beforecreate) still exists in Vue 3's Options API.

For that code snippet, the only differences in Vue 3 would be:

1. The creation of the app instance is now done via [`Vue.createApp()`](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#createapp).

   *Note: In the following example, we're using [`extends: App`](https://vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#extends) here so that we could add the `beforeCreate()` hook. Otherwise, we could simply do `createApp(App)` instead.*
2. The Vue plugins are installed off of the app instance's [`use()`](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-use) method.
3. The mounting is done via the app instance's [`mount()`](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-mount) method.

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

1️⃣
createApp({
    extends: App,
    beforeCreate() { this.$store.commit('initialiseStore') }
  })
  2️⃣
  .use(router)
  .use(store)
  3️⃣
  .mount('#app')
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-before-create-app?file=src%2Fmain.js)

**Side note:** Since you're migrating to Vue 3, [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/migration-vuex.html) is now the [officially recommended state management library](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#pinia) that replaces Vuex (now deprecated). See [Pinia's migration guide](https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/migration-vuex.html).